# Mountain Lion on Macbook Air

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, upgrade

Just got a MacBook Air, and it is running OSX 10.7.4.

Is it possible to upgrade to 10.8 (Mountain Lion)?

Are there any benefits to doing so?

What is the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes

200 new features: http://www.apple.com/osx/

You download the OS via the App Store, which you'll find in your applications folder. If you bought your Mac recently you may be eligible for a free upgrade. Check here: http://www.apple.com/osx/uptodate/

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the model you have. From [apple.com/osx/how-to-upgrade](http://www.apple.com/osx/how-to-upgrade/):

> Your Mac must be one of the following models:
>
> - iMac (Mid 2007 or newer)
> - MacBook (Late 2008 Aluminum, or Early 2009 or newer)
> - MacBook Pro (Mid/Late 2007 or newer)
> - MacBook Air (Late 2008 or newer)
> - Mac mini (Early 2009 or newer)
> - Mac Pro (Early 2008 or newer)
> - Xserve (Early 2009)
>
> If you are running Lion, you can find out if your current Mac qualifies by clicking the Apple icon at the top left of your screen, choosing About This Mac, then clicking More Info.